# IndexError: list index out of range Exception in Tkinter callback

Tags: python, tkinter, indexoutofrangeexception

I am creating an GUI for the wandrer game. After every two move of Hero, the characters move one tile as well.here I am trying to limited the movement of my characters(They cant move out of canvas and to the tiles which are wall) here is my code:

main.py

```
 m = Map.matrix
def coords(char):
    x, y = char.get_coordinates()
    x, y = int(x / 72), int(y / 72)
    return x, y

def leftKey(event):
    if m[coords(hero)[1]][coords(hero)[0] - 1] != 1 and coords(hero)[0] > 0:  # left
        hero.move(x=-72)
        hero.set_image(hero_left)
        game.move_skeleton()
        draw_canvas()

def rightKey(event):
    if m[coords(hero)[1]][coords(hero)[0] + 1] != 1 and coords(hero)[0] <= 9:  # right
        hero.move(x=72)
        hero.set_image(hero_right)
        game.move_skeleton()
        draw_canvas()

def upKey(event):
    if m[coords(hero)[1] - 1][coords(hero)[0]] != 1 and coords(hero)[1] > 0:  # up
        hero.move(y=-72)
        hero.set_image(hero_up)
        game.move_skeleton()
        draw_canvas()

def downKey(event):
    if m[coords(hero)[1] + 1][coords(hero)[0]] != 1 and coords(hero)[1] <= 9:  # down
      hero.move(y=72)
      hero.set_image(hero_down)
      game.move_skeleton()
      draw_canvas()
```

and here is game.py

```
    def move_skeleton(self):
    m = Map.matrix
    if self.hero.count % 2 == 0 :
        for char in self.characters:
            movement= [[char.x -72, char.y],[char.x, char.y -72] ,[char.x +72, char.y],[char.x , char.y +72]]
            good_movement = []
            for neighbor in movement:
                x , y = neighbor
                if m[int(y/72)][int(x/72)] !=1 and y>=0 and  y<9 * 72 and x >=0 and y<9*72:
                    good_movement.append(neighbor)
            random_movement = good_movement[random.randint(0, len(good_movement)-1)]
            char.x += random_movement[0]
            char.y += random_movement[1]
```

when i run this code I get an error as below:

```
 File "/Users/roxana/Desktop/WandererGame/main.py", line 91, in downKey
    game.move_skeleton()
  File "/Users/roxana/Desktop/WandererGame/game.py", line 96, in move_skeleton
    if m[int(y/72)][int(x/72)] !=1 and y>=0 and  y<9 * 72 and x >=0 and y<9*72:
IndexError: list index out of range
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
```

here is the my values in debbuger:
[image]

Comment: You need to swap the two sides of all of your `and`s, so that you check for the coordinates being in range before trying to use them as indexes.

Comment: You need to verify that your indexes are what you think they should be, and then examine your data to see if it's what you think it should be. And, like jasonharper said, you need to validate that the indexes are correct before you use them.

Comment: @jasonharper can you please show me what I need to do in the code?

Comment: @BryanOakley can you please explain how I Can do that in the code?

Comment: To check whether a value is what You think it should be You can just use `print()` and then print the value.

Comment: I am getting expected values actually, as you can see i have added a picture of my debugger